# What is a good approach to determining which Team Site Collections we can archive?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, team-sites

I've got a SharePoint 2010 Farm with Self Service Site Creation enabled. Years ago we were directed to roll out SharePoint as quickly as possible and let employees provision sites at will. You can guess how that turned out. We have well over a thousand site collections and most have been abandoned.

What recommendations do you have for detecting which sites are not being used and can be archived? I'm interested in as automated a process as possible.

If we could determine which site collections haven't had any content modified in two years or has not been accessed by any employee in over a year, that would probably give us a solid list of what can be archived.

Comment: This should get you started: http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/get-sitecollection-and-subsite-lastmodifieddate-and-size.html

Answer (score 0):

SPSite has members to tell you the last time content was modified (LastContentModifiedDate) and the last time security was modified (LastSecurityModifiedDate).

SPWeb has a member LastItemModifiedDate

Those should be helpful?